# Работа с разреженной матрицей в с++

Tags: c

Всем привет! Работал над одной программой, программа отвратительная, но необходимо чтобы она работала. Хоть как-то. Программа вроде как генерирует массив чисел, а потом выводит его в двух видах:

Первый - вывод с нулевыми элементами, то есть обычный вывод заполненной матрицы, не могу его реализовать, поэтому сюда и пишу.
Второй - вывод матрицы с исключенными нулевыми элементами и индексами каждого элемента, второй способ работает удовлетворительно.

Программу пишу на Visual Studio 2017.
Вот код, прошу обратить внимание на функцию void Prostoivuvod и void add:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <conio.h>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
float Scaner();

struct Node {
    int Dat;
    int i;
    int j;
    Node *next;
};

void add(Node *&lst, int i, int j, int val);
void Prostoivuvod(Node *temp, int m, int n);
void Indexvuvod(Node *temp, int m, int n);

void Prostoivuvod(Node *temp, int m, int n) {
    cout << "\nПростой вывод (с нулевыми элементами):\n";

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            // мой вывод
            cout << temp->next[i][j];

            // вывод правильный, но с исключенными нулевыми элементами
            /*while (temp != nullptr) {
                cout << temp->Dat;
                temp = temp->next;
                cout << "\n";
            }*/

            // вывод с ошибкой
            /*if (temp->next > 0) {
                printf(" %d ", temp->Dat);
            }*/
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

void Indexvuvod(Node *temp, int m, int n) {
    cout << "\nВывод с индексами (нулевые элементы исключены):\n";

    while (temp != nullptr) {
        printf("  [%d][%d]:%d", temp->i, temp->j, temp->Dat);
        temp = temp->next;
        cout << "\n";
    }

    cout << "\n";
}

void add(Node *&lst, int i, int j, int val) {
    Node *temp = new Node;
    temp->Dat = val;
    temp->i = i;
    temp->j = j;
    temp->next = nullptr;

    if (lst == nullptr) {
        lst = temp;
    }
    else {
        Node *ptr = lst;
        while (ptr->next != nullptr) {
            ptr = ptr->next;
        }
        ptr->next = temp;
    }
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");

    Node *list = nullptr;

    int m, n, val;

    cout << " > Введите кол-во строк матрицы:\n";
    cout << " > ";
    m = (int)Scaner();

    cout << " > Введите кол-во столбцов матрицы:\n";
    cout << " > ";
    n = (int)Scaner();

    int x = 0, y = 0;

    srand(unsigned int(time(0)));

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            if (rand() % 101 < 30) {
                val = rand() % 20 + 1;
                /*cout << val << endl;*/
                add(list, i, j, val);
            }
        }
    }

    /*if (*list != ptr) {

    }*/
        // сделать проверку, если в масиве были одни нули, то выдать сообщение

    Prostoivuvod(list, m, n);
    Indexvuvod(list, m, n);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

float Scaner() {
    bool good = true;
    float a;
    do {
        cin >> a;
        if (!(good = cin.good())) {
            good = false;
            cout << " [ERROR] Некорректное значение, повторите попытку:" << endl;
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            cout << " > ";
        }
        else {
            good = true;
        }
    } while (!good);
    return a;
}
```

Comment: `temp->next[i][j];` - ?? Что означают эти индексы, и в какую память Вы с их помощью залезаете?

Comment: Написана какая-то дичайшая белиберда. Это, по-видимому, означает, что остальной код писал другой человек. Не может быть так, чтобы автор `add` вдруг стал пороть такую чушь, как `temp->next[i][j]`.

Comment: @AnT Мы здесь все немножко психологи и ясновидцы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
    if (temp && temp->i == i && temp->j == j) {
      cout << temp->Dat << " "; 
      temp = temp->next;
    } else {
      cout << "0 ";
    }
  }
  cout << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Надо же, простейшего условия не хватало. Спасибо тебе!